# what is the Maple translation for this Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, maple, code-translation

```
uu = polyval(polyfit(x,u,N),xx); % interpolate grid data
```

The code above is written in Matlab. How to write this statement in Maple?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). You need to ask a specific question after you have made an attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown use your example data for `x`, `u`, or `xx`. So I'll make some up.

The following generates `P3` which can be applied elementwise to Vector `xx`. It interpolates the degree N-1 polynomial at each point of `xx`.

```
restart;
Digits:=15:
N:=20:
(a,b):=0,2*Pi:
x:=Vector([seq(evalf(a)..evalf(b), evalf((b-a)/(N-1)))],
          datatype=float[8]):
u:=map(sin, x):
xx:=Vector([seq(evalf(a)..evalf(b), 0.5)],
           datatype=float[8]):

P3:=Interpolation:-SplineInterpolation(x,u,degree=N-1,
      endpoints=notaknot):

P3~(xx);
```

The call `P3~(xx)` acts element-by-element. But the interpolating function returned by that `Interpolate` command also knows how to act automatically (elementwise) of the whole of Vector `xx`, so the following should be more efficient,

```
P3(xx);
```

That example is 1-D data. There are other ways to get a similar result, generating the polynomial interpolant explicitly. But they are less efficient when evaluating across the `xx` data.

```
restart;
Digits:=15:
N:=20:  (a,b):=0,2*Pi:
x:=Vector([seq(evalf(a)..evalf(b), evalf((b-a)/(N-1)))],
          datatype=float[8]):
u:=map(sin, x):
xx:=Vector([seq(evalf(a)..evalf(b), 0.5)],
           datatype=float[8]):
P1:=unapply(CurveFitting:-PolynomialInterpolation(x,u,'t'),'t'):
P2:=unapply(CurveFitting:-Spline(x,u,'t',degree=N-1,endpoints=notaknot),'t'):
P3:=Interpolation:-SplineInterpolation(x,u,degree=N-1,endpoints=notaknot):
sin~(xx);
P1~(xx);
P2~(xx);
P3~(xx);
plots:-display(
 plot(sin, a..b, color=gray),
 plots:-pointplot(<xx|P1~(xx)>, color=blue, symbol=circle, symbolsize=25),
 plots:-pointplot(<xx|P2~(xx)>, color=red, symbol=circle, symbolsize=16),
 plots:-pointplot(<xx|P3~(xx)>, color=black, symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=5)
);
```

If you have data `x`, `u`, and `xx` of greater dimension (eg, 2-D) then please provide an explicit example in more detail.

[edit] Here is data that may conform more to your example provided (later) in comments. The results of the four methods (to produce a degree 16 polynomial) agree reasonable well with each other. They also seem to agree quite well with the `uu` computed by Matlab.

What should matter to you is the accuracy  with which the interpolating polynomial provides when *evaluated* across the desired range (ie, `xx`). What should *not* matter to you is whether the particular coefficients from one approach match closely with the coefficients from another approach.

The approach using Interpolation:-SplineInterpolation is the most efficient of these four.

```
restart;
Digits := 15:
x := <1.0000e+00,9.8079e-01,9.2388e-01,8.3147e-01,7.0711e-01,5.5557e-01,
  3.8268e-01,1.9509e-01,6.1232e-17,-1.9509e-01,-3.8268e-01,-5.5557e-01,
  -7.0711e-01,-8.3147e-01,-9.2388e-01,-9.8079e-01,-1.0000e+00>:
u := <0,-0.2197,-0.7659,-1.3860,-1.8554,-2.0776,-2.0706,-1.9031,
  -1.6443,-1.3454,-1.0405,-0.7524,-0.4970,-0.2863,-0.1294,-0.0327,0>:
xx := <seq(-1..1,0.01)>:
exact := map(t->evalhf((exp(4*t)-sinh(4)*t-cosh(4))/16), xx):

P3:=Interpolation:-SplineInterpolation(x,u,degree=16,endpoints=notaknot):
uu3 := P3(xx):
plots:-display(
  plot([ <xx|(uu3)> ], style=point, color=black),
  plot(t->(exp(4*t)-sinh(4)*t-cosh(4))/16, -1..1, color=red)
);
plot([ <xx|(uu3-exact)> ]):

P4 := unapply(Statistics:-PolynomialFit(16, x, u, 't'), 't'):
uu4 := map[evalhf](P4,xx):
plot([ <xx|(uu4-exact)> ]);
plots:-display(
  plot([ <xx|(uu4)> ], style=point, color=black),
  plot(t->(exp(4*t)-sinh(4)*t-cosh(4))/16, -1..1, color=red)
);

P1:=unapply(CurveFitting:-PolynomialInterpolation(x,u,'t'),'t'):
uu1 := map[evalhf](P1,xx):
plot([ <xx|(uu1-exact)> ]);
plots:-display(
  plot([ <xx|(uu1)> ], style=point, color=black),
  plot(t->(exp(4*t)-sinh(4)*t-cosh(4))/16, -1..1, color=red)
);

P2:=unapply(CurveFitting:-Spline(x,u,'t',degree=16,endpoints=notaknot),'t'):
uu2 := map[evalhf](P2,xx):
plot([ <xx|(uu2-exact)> ]);
plots:-display(
  plot([ <xx|(uu2)> ], style=point, color=black),
  plot(t->(exp(4*t)-sinh(4)*t-cosh(4))/16, -1..1, color=red)
);
```

Comment: Executing your code on my values returns quite different values from the Matlab code. I figured out the translation of the inner parentheses, `polyfit(x,u,N)`, which will be `P3 := ArrayTools:-FlipDimension(Statistics:-PolynomialFit(N, x, u), 1)` in Maple. Now, looking for the equivalent of Matlab expression `uu=Polyval(P3,xx)` in Maple.

Comment: Here is the whole program code in Matlab:
`N = 16;
x = cos(pi*(0:N)/N)';
c = [2; ones(N-1,1); 2].*(-1).^(0:N)';
X = repmat(x,1,N+1);
dX = X-X';
D = (c*(1./c)')./(dX+(eye(N+1))); % off-diagonal entries
D = D - diag(sum(D')); % diagonal entries
D2 = D^2;
D2 = D2(2:N,2:N); % boundary conditions
f = exp(4*x(2:N));
u = D2\f; % Poisson eq. solved here
u = [0;u;0];
xx = -1:.01:1;
P3=polyfit(x,u,N);
uu = polyval(P3,xx); % interpolate grid data
exact = ( exp(4*xx) - sinh(4)*xx - cosh(4) )/16; `

Comment: I have added code that is closer to the `x`, `u`, and `xx` data that your Matlab example produces.

Comment: note: 1) I used the `x`, and `u` data rounded to 5 places, so don't fret over comparison with the "exact" vaues, or with of the generated `uu` in Maple versus the `uu` in Matlab (the latter uses more digits of input). 2) It may not matter here, but `PolynomialFit` is not generally the most robust method for constructing the interpolating polynomial.  3) `SplineInterpolation` may be better, even if the alternate explicit ploynomials are converted to horner form prior to `unapply`. 4) I don't know why you prefer a single high degree poly, over say piecewise spline lower degree.